# SQLAlchemy: one to "fixed number" relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationships

Lets say I have a basic table setup like this:

```
class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'
    car_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    someotherinfo = Column(String)

class Tire(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tires'
    tire_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    car_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Car.car_id'))
    someotherinfo = Column(String)
```

I now want a relationship between car and tire, such that each car has exactly 4 tires associated with it.
For this, I could add to the Car definition:

```
tire1 = relationship("Tire", uselist=False, backref="car")
tire2 = relationship("Tire", uselist=False, backref="car")
tire3 = relationship("Tire", uselist=False, backref="car")
tire4 = relationship("Tire", uselist=False, backref="car")
```

But this wouldn't allow me to iterate over the tires (in my real problem there are more than 4 tires). Something else would be:

```
tires = relationship('Tire', backref='car')
```

But this doesn't restrict tires to maximum of 4, and doesn't allow me to access a specific tire (I guess the tires list is not necessarily  ordered).
So what I would want is something like this:

```
tires = relationship('Tire', backref='car', max=4, usearray=True)
```

where I can specifically address a certain tire (array is sorted), restrict it to 4, and am able to iterate over them.

This is my first question, I hope it is clear and please correct me if I did something wrong.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would solve your problem with an associative table.

```
class TireCar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tire_car_assoc'
    tire_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    car_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order = Column(Integer)
    someotherinfo = Column(String)
```

where you could also define `tire_id` and `car_id` as `ForeignKey` of course.

This way you can iterate the relation or do whatever you need you need to do. If you can only have 4 relations (or `n` in your real problem) between the two tables, I would control that in `python`.

(The way I usually reason about `SLQAlchemy`, or any `orm` for that matter, is that it does not do anything essentially different to the database. I'd say, then, design always your solution with your mind in the database, and implement it with the `orm`. Maybe you don't particularly like my solution, it is probably incomplete, besides you have the information of your functional model! But I hope it helps you to find your own solution.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To be honest, I don't really see a difference between this and adding
`tires = relationship('Tire', backref='car')`
to Class Car and
`order = Column(Integer)`
to tire.
In both cases I would need to control the max number of tires and restrict order to be unique per car in python. Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, in both cases you'll have to control the maximum number of tyres. The difference of this solution is that you can iterate the relations between cars and tyres, and that you can add attributes to this relations in a clean way. Is order an attribute of the tyre, or does it belong to the relation between car and tyre? It depends on your model, but in my opinion this is cleaner. Sometimes when we use an orm  we think about programming only and we forget we are leaving a data model behind. Whatever makes more functional sense would be the right way to do it!